# Is that a regular express? Proof using closure properties or pumping theorem

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

I am studying regular express. I understand how to proof a x<sup>a</sup> y<sup>a</sup>. However, I don't know how to proof the below problem. Please help me.

L = { x<sup>a</sup> y<sup>b</sup> | a ≠ b }

Comment: Try using closure properties to relate your language to the one you know how to handle. It’s also possible to use the pumping lemma directly, but it requires a trick.

Comment: Yes. But I don't know how to use closure properties. Could you teach me with this sample?

Comment: Your language appears in our reference question.